# Creating Microsoft Word (.docx) documents in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ms-word, documents

Is there an easy way to create Word documents (.docx) in a Ruby application? Actually, in my case it's a Rails application served from a Linux server.

A gem similar to [Prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/) but for [DOCX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOCX) instead of PDF would be great!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As has been noted, there don't appear to be any libraries to manipulate Open XML documents in Ruby, but [OpenXML Developer](http://openxmldeveloper.org/) has complete documentation on the format of Open XML documents.

If what you want is to send a copy of a standard document (like a form letter) customized for each user, it should be fairly simple given that a DOCX is a ZIP file that contains various parts in a directory hierarchy. Have a DOCX "template" that contains all the parts and tree structure that you want to send to `all` users (with no real content), then simply create new (or modify existing) pieces that contain the user-specific content you want and inject it into the ZIP (DOCX file) before sending it to the user.

For example: You could have `document-template.xml` that contains *Dear [USER-PLACEHOLDER]:*. When a user requests the document, you replace `[USER-PLACEHOLDER]` with the user's name, then add the resulting `document.xml` to the `your-template.docx` ZIP file (which would contain all the images and other parts you want in the Word document) and send that resulting document to the user.

Note that if you rename a `.docx` file to `.zip` it is trivial to explore the structure and format of the parts inside. You can remove or replace images or other parts very easily with any ZIP manipulation tools or programmatically with code.

Generating a brand new Word document with completely custom content from raw XML would be very difficult without access to an API to make the job easier. If you really need to do that, you might consider installing [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), then use VB.NET, C# or [IronRuby](http://www.ironruby.net/) to create your Open XML documents using the [Open XML Format SDK 1.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx). Since you would just be using the [Microsoft.Office.DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.documentformat.openxml.packaging.aspx) to manipulate Open XML documents, it should work okay in Mono, which seems to support everything the SDK requires.

Comment: I've written a small utility for slicing up somewhat complex docx templates and building a custom document using the slices: http://github.com/bagilevi/docx_builder

Comment: nice still trying to get my head around a table loop using this method

Comment: I've added another option for generating a docx file from a template https://github.com/jawspeak/ruby-docx-templater It uses zipruby and processes in-memory. (Actually it uses a forked version that does not collide with rubyzip's Zip:: module).

Comment: What about using Google Docs as converting service. So it will allow export document to *.doc, *.pdf, *.xls. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#downloading_documents_and_files. And few gems to work with Docs http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=gdata

Answer (score 12):

Maybe this gem is interesting for you.

https://github.com/trade-informatics/caracal/

It like prawn but with docx.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/). It is written in Java, but [integrates with Ruby as an extension](http://poi.apache.org/poi-ruby.html)

Comment: Thanks for your input! Do you know of any implementation where Apache POI was used to actually create a word document (not only parse it)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about it other than it exists.

Comment: docx4j (my project) is focused on doing stuff with docx files (as opposed to xlsx, though it handles those as well)

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question but there's a new answer. If you'd like to turn an HTML doc into a Word (docx) doc, just use the 'htmltoword' gem:

https://github.com/karnov/htmltoword

I'm not sure why there was answer creep and everyone started posting templating solutions, but this answers the OP's question. Just like Prawn, except Word instead of PDF.

**UPDATE:**

There's also [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) and an API wrapper for pandoc called [docverter](http://www.docverter.com/). Both have slightly complicated installs since pandoc is a haskell library.

Comment: I used `htmltoword` and can't recommend it. It can only handle paragraphs and headers. If you want powerful document conversion in your Ruby app, I suggest Pandoc, though a ruby wrapper like docverter or pandoc-ruby. PDF conversion requires LaTeX libraries though - it's nearly 2GB of libraries. Fair warning :)

Comment: I found a more serious issue with htmltoword.. The docx isn't quite right with word. It shows up fine, but if there's a spelling mistake in the source word can't see it. The mistake won't even be caught if you run a manual spell check. So it diminishes words usefulness

Comment: This isn't really "Just like Prawn", since Prawn allows all kinds of options for specifically configuring the output file. This is just a converter.

But it looks like it will be sufficient for my use case.

Answer (score 7):

I know if you serve a HTML document as a word document with the .doc extension, it will open in Word just fine. Just don't do anything fancy.

**Edit:** Here is an example using classic ASP. http://www.aspdev.org/asp/asp-export-word/

Comment: Thanks, but that sounds a bit like a dirty hack, doesn't it? :-) Besides that: What are the security concerns when using RTF?

Comment: What are the concerns with RTF files?

Answer (score 4):

Using a technique very similar to that suggested by Grant Wagner I have created a Ruby html to word gem that should allow you to easily output Word docx files from your ruby app. You can check it out at http://github.com/nickfrandsen/htmltoword - Simply pass it a html string and it will create a corresponding word docx file.

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.docx do
      file = Htmltoword::Document.create params[:docx_html_source], "file_name.docx"
      send_file file.path, :disposition => "attachment"
    end
  end
end
```

Hope you find it useful. If you have any problems with it feel free to open a github issue.

Comment: Once I use `create_and_save` method It saved at given path in zipped file but unable to find `.docx' format file ..Please Advise !!!

Comment: Does this gem allow for you to control the page orientation?

Answer (score 4):

Disclosure: I'm the leader of the docxtemplater project.

I know you're looking for a ruby solution, but because all other solutions only tell you how to do it globally, without giving you a library that does exactly what you want, here's a solution based on JS or NodeJS (works in both)

[DocxTemplater Library](https://github.com/edi9999/docxtemplater)

[Demo of the library](http://javascript-ninja.fr/docxgenjs/examples/demo.html)

You can also use it in the commandline:

```
npm install docxtemplater -g

docxtemplater <configFile>

----config.docxFile: The input file in docx format
----config.outputFile: The outputfile of the document
```

Comment: giving a js example for a ruby question is bad taste.

Comment: There's also a command line interface, so maybe this could be useful for projects not using node.js

Answer (score 3):

This is a way Doccy ([doccyapp.com](https://www.doccyapp.com)) has a api that does just that which you can use. Supports docx, odt and pages and converts to PDF as well if you like

Answer (score 2):

Further to Grant's answer, you can also send Word a "Flat OPC" file, which is essentially the docx unzipped and concatenated to create a single xml file. This way, you can replace [USER-PLACEHOLDER] in one file and be done with it (ie no zipping or unzipping).

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still looking at this, this post explains how to use an XML data source.  This works nicely for me.

http://seroter.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/populating-word-2007-templates-through-open-xml/

Answer (score 2):

Check out this github repo: https://github.com/jawspeak/ruby-docx-templater

It allows you to create a document from a word template.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on Windows, of course, it's a matter of WIN32OLE and some pain with the Word COM objects.

Chances are that your serving from a *nix environment, though. Word 2007 uses the "[Microsoft Office Open XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML)" format (*.docx) which can be opened using the appropriate [compatibility pack from Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HA100444731033.aspx).

Some of the more recent Office apps (2002/XP and 2003 at least) had [their own XML formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats) which may also be useable.

I'm not aware of any Ruby tools to make the process easier, sadly.

If it can be made acceptable, I think I'd be inclined to go down the renamed-html file route. I just saved a document as HTML from WordXP, renamed it to a .doc and opened it without problem.

Comment: The renamed-html file route as you describe it wouldn't work for my case. I can't pre-build the html-files in an office word application and rename it to .doc and if I do this with plain html-files on my server they aren't recognized by IE as doc-files.

Comment: Im not fan of Win32OLE as it uses the word engine to manipulate the file.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. Unfortunately I could not manipulate the xml because my clients should themselves to fill in templates. And to do this is not always possible (for example, office for mac does not allow this).

As a solution to this problem, I made ​​a simple gem, which can be used as an rtf document template with embedded ruby: https://github.com/eicca/rtf-templater

I tested it and it works ok for filling reports and documents. However, formatting badly displays for complex loops and conditions.