# What's the best way to generate Microsoft OOXML (docx) from a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, docx, openxml

What's the best way to generate Microsoft OOXML (docx) from a Ruby on Rails app?

I'm guessing it's not using ruby.

At the moment we use the rtf gem (http://rubygems.org/gems/rtf) to generate a document that can be completed from Microsoft Word. The document includes multiple header types, tables, and a few images.

but the RTF extensions we use to build tables and images are MSWord specific. Using OOXML, we'll get better compatibility with Word and also other apps. Unfortunately ODS is not an option, as there's an intention to use an ooxml-based iPad editor as well.

Also, it should be noted this would not be served off a Windows host, and therefore the relevant win32/.net libraries are not available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Microsoft Word (.docx) documents in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697505/creating-microsoft-word-docx-documents-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Michael, but since that question was asked I've had to implement this myself and wrote up some [notes](http://rubythings.blogspot.com/2011/05/creating-word-documents-in-rails.html) that might help