# creating a simple report in Apple Pages using OpenXML or other format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ms-word, openxml

I'm interesting in outputting some information from a rails web app to an Apple Pages document. I have never done this before. Supposedly, Apple Pages support OpenXML. Is there a suitable modern gem for help in doing this? Is there something simpler than OpenXML for writing the pages file? Would an OpenXML doc be compatible between Apple Pages and Microsoft Word? Would the information here http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/07/02/5389.aspx be pertinent to an Apple Pages document?

I know this is a somewhat vague question - I have looked at some of the resources such as this question [Creating Microsoft Word (.docx) documents in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697505/creating-microsoft-word-docx-documents-in-ruby) but they don't seem to add much to what I'm trying to achieve. It doesn't seem possible to save a Pages doc as a Word docx (just a doc) so I'm not even sure if using OpenXML is feasible.

One suggestion has been to use an Azure AWS instance and post data to it which will have the OpenXML sdk.

What would be a reasonable / best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

[Creating Microsoft Word (.docx) documents in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697505/creating-microsoft-word-docx-documents-in-ruby)

Perhaps install Mono, which supports OpenXML and IronRuby. However, using C# directly is much easier.