# Export MS Word file Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, export

I want to export `MS Word` file from Rails 3.2 application. Is there any gem to generate `MS Word` file in Rails application?

This file will contain a table consisting of users fetched from the DB on some criteria.

Table will look like this.

```
Name | Email | Rate
john | ------| 10
kethi| ------| 15
```

Comment: You're better off exporting a **csv**. I don't think there are any gems that have this (exporting from word) functionality, and you'd need intimate knowledge of how Microsoft Word formats its documents to create one. Frankly, it's **not been worth the effort** for anyone, which is why there aren't any gems.

Comment: After some research, here is a link I found on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697505/creating-microsoft-word-docx-documents-in-ruby

For your needs though, I think a CSV is a better option.