# How to convert csv to word with ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ms-word

I am new to Ruby on rails. I am trying to convert a csv file to word document using ROR. The csv file is the output of sql query that I ran in SQL server management studio.

1) Is there a way to use ROR directly on SQL server management studio to get the desired result(Here ms word document) or Is it necessary to export as csv from sql server and then use ROR to get the MS Word document

2) Can ROR help us to neatly format the output in Word document say with Tables

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use freetds to connect to sqlserver from rails app. Its really very simple.

Install the library `freetds-dev`. Install `tiny-tds` and `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` gems.
And then read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697505/creating-microsoft-word-docx-documents-in-ruby) to get an idea on generating word document in rails app.